# How can I make a Internet audio streaming server?

Tags: http-live-streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I need to make a internet radio server, how can I do that on top of apache. Want to understand the architecture of the whole system. Are there some good reads ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Tutorial about using **[IceCast](http://www.icecast.org/)**, a free server software for streaming multimedia.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAudioStreaming.html